# Does use of absolute layout in xml file really makes problem for using on different density emulator

Tags: android, layout, emulation

i have used absolute layout in order to display image buttons in my application's main.xml.
   how exactly it affects to using my app on different density screens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute Layout is deprecated and should not be used, it will make a mess of handling various screens. 
[Best practices for screen layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence)

Answer (score 1):

That is right, absolute layout will always make problem, that is why it is not at all recommended to use. 
Please refer this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)